# Using data from one ajax request in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm learning ruby but am going to need some JS/Jquery for a small project I'm working on with a friend.  We're using the Last.fm api and are trying to build a page where we're going to call from two different URL's for Json data.

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=rj&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json

Where we can pull out the friends username and some info about them, and

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=rj&period=7day&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json

where we can get the top tracks for each user.

The main problem I'm running in to is, once I pull out the username, I need to store it as a variable and then insert it inside the '&user=rj&' on get toptoptracks to be able to pull each users top tracks.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=rj&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        $('#success #f1').html(data.friends.user[0].name);
        $('#success #f2').html(data.friends.user[1].name);
        $('#success #f3').html(data.friends.user[2].name);
    },
    error : function(code, message){
        $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + code + ', Error Message: ' + message);            
    }
});
```

is what I have so far (also one for toptracks, reading up on nesting them now), but I'm not sure how to get their user name AND store it as a variable to use inside the top tracks (.each do for JS?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can't do threads like other languages such as java. To get round this, it sets handlers - functions that will be run later when triggered by some event. When you call `$.ajax({ ... });`, javascript sets the handler but immediately continues running. The success handler won't run until later, after the ajax response is received. So any code placed after `$.ajax({ ... });` will run immediately. If you want something to run after the response is received, you have to put it inside the success handler. Like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var users = data.friends.user;
    $.each(users, function(i, user) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=' + user + '&period=7day&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json',
            ...
            success: function(data) { ... },
            ...
        });
    });
},
```

(Note: The way I've generated the URL is BAD. A username containing `&` would confuse the server, probably giving malicious users too much control over the command sent. You should URI-escape `user`.)

This works if you just have one handler for each user. For example, if each friend has a section of the page, you can update each section as its results come in. But if you have a function that you want to run after *all* data has been received, it gets a little more tricky. In that case you should probably learn to use a library such as async or Q. Although I'm not sure that async is even available for client-side javascript.

Comment: I was able to mess around with this and get it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, something like this might help get you started:

```
// at the top of your script create empty users var
var users = [];

// create a function that generates your endpoint url

var urlWithUser = function(user){
  return 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=' + user + '&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json'
};

// assign value to users
var getInitialData = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=rj&api_key=3d7e6bb560deeb5d15af8176abf5c928&format=json',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            users = data.friends.user;
            $.each(users, function(index, value){
                getUserData(this.name);
            };
        },
        error : function(code, message){
            $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + code + ', Error Message: ' + message);            
        }
    });
};

// create a function with your ajax call, which can be used to obtain specific user data
var getUserData  = function(user){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : urlWithUser(user);
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            // do whatever you want
        },
        error : function(code, message){
            $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + code + ', Error Message: ' + message);            
        }
    });
};

// get first set of users
getInitialData();
```

Note `urlWithUser` which accepts a user param and is used to generate specific endpoint for you.

Comment: This won't work. The `$.each` loop at the end will run before the success handler in `getInitialData`, while `users` is empty; `getUserData` will never run. You need to put the loop inside the success handler.

Comment: good catch, i've updated my response to include this in the success handler.